# doing calculations on specific columns of array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I populated a dynamic array using the data from a Table specific only on those rows that have a specific value in a specific column. Until this moment no probs. I'm unable though to do operations referred to one entire column (and only that column).

I thought about something like this

```
Dim arr as variant
Dim avg as double
Dim i as integer
i = InputBox( "The column I want to calculate the average of")
 avg = Application.Worksheetfunction.Average(arr.column(i))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have some sample data to go with this? Along with expected output and current result.

Comment: I DID IT! the code i used was: avg = application.worksheetfunction.average(application.index(array,0,i))

Comment: @FilippoMhri As this is now solved can you either close your question or better yet, write your comment as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to change "column" to "columns"

Solution:

```
avg = Application.Worksheetfunction.Average(arr.columns(i))
```

Comment: How does this work? I can't get it to work with an array

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the average of an array? Simply do:
```Application.Worksheetfunction.Average(ArrayName)```

Comment: that doesn’t work on a non-2D array which is what the question is asking

Answer (score 1):

another possibility, worse in this case is the code i used was:

avg = application.worksheetfunction.average(application.index(array,0,i)) –